# Get clicked pixel coordinates in photo overlay in Google Earth plugin

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-earth-plugin

I am  using Google Earth Plugin api to display large images as photo overlay (using image pyramid: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/photos). That works just fine.

However, now I need to add a user ability to mark a point on the image.

My questions:

1) Is it possible?

2) If not, are there other methods to display large images (vertical/diagonal) in google earth which allow this ability?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, if the image is an overlay on the earth then each point of the image must correspond to a point on the earth.

It would simply be a case of allowing the user to put placemarks via clicking on the image.

There are a couple of tools that allow you to slice up large photos into image pyramids.
The first one "GMap Image Cutter"actually shows an example of the 'placemark for an image' idea in the output.

GMap Image Cutter - http://www.bartlett.ucl.ac.uk/casa/latest/software/gmap-image-cutter

MapTiler - http://www.maptiler.org/